# Ошибка с инициализацией переменной

Tags: c++, c

Я не могу понять почему компилятор выдает мне ошибку `Ошибка C4700 использована неинициализированная локальная переменная "TempNode"`. Вот мой код:

```
void PushFront(T Value)
    {
        Node<T>* TempNode;
        TempNode->NextNode = PtrBegin->NextNode;
        TempNode->Value = PtrBegin->Value;
        PtrBegin->Value = Value;
        PtrBegin->NextNode = (Node<T>*)malloc(sizeof(Node<T>));
        PtrBegin->NextNode = TempNode->NextNode;
        PtrBegin->Value = TempNode->Value;
    }
```

Реализация `Node`:

```
struct Node
    {
    public:
        Node* NextNode;
        TypeNode Value;
        Node() : NextNode((Node<TypeNode>*)malloc(sizeof(Node<TypeNode>))), Value(NULL) {}
        Node(TypeNode Value) : NextNode(new Node<TypeNode>), Value(Value) {}
        ~Node()
        {
            delete NextNode;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Так а где у вас делается инициализация `TempNode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void PushFront(T Value)
{
    Node<T>* TempNode;
    // чему здесь равен TempNode?
    TempNode->NextNode = PtrBegin->NextNode;
    ...
    // зачем он вообще здесь нужен?
```

Последующие присвоения разных значений одним и тем же переменным (`PtrBegin->Value` и `PtrBegin->NextNode`) в соседних строках - бессмысленны, не говоря уже о `malloc`.

Comment: Ну я как указать чему равны поля `TempNode`. А про присвоение одни и тем же переменным разные значения я немного ошибся ошибся

Comment: @PoulShipilov `new` и `delete`

Comment: new - лучше чем malloc?

Comment: @PoulShipilov да, `new` - лучше чем `malloc`

Comment: Просто с `new` в некоторых частях возникала ошибка доступа

Comment: мне трудно понять, что это значит

Comment: @PoulShipilov У переменной `TempNode` нет никаких полей, так как тип этой переменной - **указатель** на объект типа `Node<T>`.